# Cannot resolve symbol 'GCMBroadcastReceiver' in Android Studio

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to use GoogleCloudMessaging (GCM) API for push notification in my Android app.

Referring to http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/ and http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Setup, I tried to set them up in AndroidManifest.xml but it gave me some error:

- Cannot resolve symbol 'GCMBroadcastReceiver'
- Cannot resolve symbol 'GCMIntentService'

This block is in Application tag

```
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>

            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.zaqqle.disqover" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
```

I am using Android Studio and what I have done

- installed Google Play Services in SDK Manager and synced with Gradle
- included `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.23'` in build.gradle
- included `<meta-data
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
          android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />` in AndroidManifest.xml

Could you help me point out where I have missed? Thank for any help!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver` is a deprecated class that you probably don't have in your project. You should implement your own broadcast receiver. `GCMIntentService` is a class you are supposed to implement.

You are using an old tutorial that uses deprecated classes instead of using the Google Play Services library. You should refer to the current [official GCM demo app](http://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/gcm-client/GcmClient/src/main/) to see how your manifest should look like and which classes should be in the project.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your link to official demo saved my life !

Comment: Great, worked for me too. I've been googling for a while and finally i saw your "GCMIntentService is a class you are supposed to implement"

Comment: Yes and I think it is officially removed from the SDK.