# not getting the file GcmBroadcastReceiver and InAppNotificationActivity in xml

Tags: android

cannot find GcmBroadcastReceiver i made GcmBroadcastReceiver  class but in my AndroidManifest file i am getting error its not getting the file GcmBroadcastReceiver in xml

```
<receiver
            android:name="com.clevertap.android.sdk.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
                <action
                    android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
                <category android:name="com.vedicrishiastro.kundli"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.clevertap.android.sdk.InAppNotificationActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"/>

    </application>



GcmBroadcastReceiver.class

public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    }
}
```

Comment: what error u r getting in the logcat , can u post that line

Comment: @Edgarprabhu in my AndroidManifest com.clevertap.android.sdk.""GcmBroadcastReceiver"" is in red

Comment: u xml right, do u find any error in ur xml?

Comment: yes it cannot locate com.clevertap.android.sdk.GcmBroadcastReceiver

Comment: are u trying to run this project only https://github.com/CleverTap/clevertap-android-sdk

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23520771/4085446

Comment: Its working fine only

Comment: can u post the  mainfest file of urs?